# WSo2 ESB 4.9.0 is not able to handle time outs and servers are going down

Tags: wso2-esb

We are seeing this issue in product when any of the back end servers then ESB servers are stumbling. Why the ESB is not able to handle time outs gracefully.

Did anyone experienced it, not sure product is missing anything here.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the global timeout by modifying the 'synapse.global_timeout_interval' property (in ms) in the synapse.properties file. Please find more details [here](http://soatutorials.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-configure-timeouts-in-wso2-esb.html).

Comment: If we increase the global time outs then the the incoming messages are being stuck in the memory and throwing more out of memory errors. Looks like WSO2 esb is not able to handle more load with message size more than 100KB. Now it's evident that ESB servers are getting out of memory issues when back end services throwing more time outs. For us we can mamange with the time outs if servers are stable .

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to set the responseAction as fault(under the timeout node) in backend endpoint configuration? If you set this, when timeout, ESB will going into the fault sequence.

```
<address uri="endpoint address" [format="soap11|soap12|pox|rest|get"] [optimize="mtom|swa"]
    [encoding="charset encoding"]
    [statistics="enable|disable"] [trace="enable|disable"]>

    <enableSec [policy="key"]/>?
    <enableAddressing [version="final|submission"] [separateListener="true|false"]/>?

    <timeout>
        <duration>timeout duration in milliseconds</duration>
        <responseAction>**discard|fault**</responseAction>
    </timeout>?
</address>
```